# Java: Assigning specified type to generic type

Tags: java, generics, types

Im trying to understand the following code.

```
class Test<E extends SubTest>
{
    List<Vector<E>> links;

    Test()
    {
        links = MyStaticClass.aList;
        // Where aList is static ArrayList<Vector<SubTest>>;
    }
}
```

How come assigning the following `ArrayList` to links List gives an error. Souldnt it understand the assignment considering i extended E with SubTest.

When I have a parameter T t; i can access t properties, but i cant do the said assing. Wouldnt `List<Vector<T>>` links expect to get `ArrayList<Vector<SubTest>>` anyway ?

Comment: The type is 'E extends Subtest' not 'Subtest'. Therefore, you cannot ensure that E == Subtest, it could in fact, be any subtype of Subtest.

Comment: why don't you just declare `List<Vector<SubTest>> links;`

Comment: Folks, please read the questions before answering.  The OP did not ask how to make this work - the ask was why there was an error.  Very different question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the error.

The actual problem is that `E` is not the same as `SubTest`.

If you make an instance of `Test<SubSubTest>` (where `SubSubTest` inherits `SubTest`), your code would try to put a collection of `SubTest`s (which can hold any derived class) into a variable of type `List<Vector<SubSubTest>>` (which can only hold `SubSubTest`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, in the **definition** of a class, the actual name of a class can't be used in place of the generic `E` at compile time.  Even though E is derived from Subtest, E is a generic type and Subtest is a class.  So this problem isn't caused specifically by `Subtest`, but because a **class** is being used in the place of a **generic type**.

Even though this is not directly related to your problem, it may make sense:

```
//In a generic class, the compiler won't even allow you to instantiate 
//E with new

//If you try to do this:

 E obj1;
 obj1 = new E();  

 //You will see the compiler error that E is a type parameter and a CLASS 
 //has to be used with new, not a type parameter
```

You're trying to put an actual object:  `MyStaticClass.aList` into a place where a generic type `E` is still required.

Whenever I have declared a class with a generic type, I have never been able to put in an actual class name in the place of a member of that class declared as having a generic type.  I always had to use a parameter, variable, ETC. with the generic name E that class had defined.

---

In my experience, to assign into a member variable of a class `Test` that is based on a generic E, **you have to use a variable that is directly associated with the generic E in the `Test` class**.  Even another "E" from another generic class will not work:  because that other generic "E" is not the same generic that is defined as a generic in the Test class

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    Test<SubTest> x = new Test<SubTest>();
    x.links = MyStaticClass.aList;
```

You want to instantiate the type parameter `E` with `SubTest`. That is a reasonable expectation. But the problem is that type parameters are instantiated *when the constructor is called* with the `new` keyword. Your mistake is to try to instantiate it in the body of the constructor. In the body of the constructor you should treat `E` for what it is: a parameter which has not yet been instantiated.

It is possible that later you want to instantiate `E` with `EsotericSubSubTest`. Doing the assignment in the constructor, you would assign a value of type `ArrayList<Vector<SubTest>>` to a field of type `List<Vector<EsotericSubSubTest>>` which is definitely wrong.